# Intersection of 2 arrays, O(n), in-place, only constant amount of additional memory

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

2 integer arrays, A and B, are given(integers can be negative). Goal is to find an intersection of those arrays, result should be stored in one of the initial arrays and should not contain duplicate  elements. Only constant amount of memory can be used.

Comment: Unless you do some shenanigans (which is very much possible you can)  with the fact that the elements are guaranteed integers that takes you out of algebraic model - this cannot be done, as it will allow you to solve easily [Element Distinctness Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) in linear time in algebraic model. (tl;dr: if this is possible, you somehow must exploit the fact that elements are integers)

Comment: The only way to do this in O(n) that I can see is to make my "constant amount of memory" equal to `int.MaxVal/4` (or more easily, `2*Int.MaxVal+1`).  Then it's fairly straightforward.   And yes, this would exploit the fact that the elements are integers.

Comment: Do the integers have any min/max limits?

Answer (score 3):

By first sorting the elements, (and exploiting the fact that they are integers to efficiently do it using some [integer sorting technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting) such as [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)), you can simply traverse the arrays to yield all common elements. You can store them in the beginning of one of the array (as it is guaranteed you never advance the output iterator before the input iterator is done with it.

Pseudo code:

```
FindCommons(A, B):
  IntegersSort(A)
  IntegersSort(B)
  i = j = 0
  out = 0
  while (i < length(A) && j < length(B)):
    if A[i] == B[j]:
      A[out++] = A[i]
      i++
      j++
    else if A[i] < B[j]:
      i++
    else:
      j++
  // Output is A in range (0, out) once this is completed.
```

Answer (score -1):

Using sets in python if numbers are unique